# HTML ISO-8859-2 form encoding

Tags: html, encoding, iso-8859-2

I have to send some values via post ISO-8859-2 encoded.

When the receiver got and displayed the message it was something like

`Ä…,Ä‡,Ä™,Ĺ‚,Ĺ„,Ăł,Ĺ›,Ĺş,Ĺź,Ä„,Ä†,Ä˜,Ĺ,Ĺƒ,Ă“,Ĺš,Ĺš,Ĺť`

(stack overflow cannot display all of them by paste).

The example of html page that submit form:

```html
<html>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
  function OnLoadEvent() {
    document.downloadForm.submit();
  }
</SCRIPT>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-2">
</head>

<body OnLoad="OnLoadEvent();">
  <form name="downloadForm" accept-charset="ISO-8859-2" action="https://url" method="POST">
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="Description" value="ŃÓô">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I have also write simple page to display some of the characters.
Page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-2">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  Ńóô
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

But it also displays something like that:
ĹƒĂłĂ´
Do you know what is the reason of that? If Im thinking good this charset should handle all of the latin characters.

Comment: Have you actually saved the HTML file as ISO-8859-2 in your text editor?

Comment: As you can see in the snippet I made, the codes ARE already UTF8

Comment: Note: you are using `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, so you declare the browser you use html5, but so you should use utf-8. Do no mix standards and encoding. Remove the DOCTYPE or set it appropriately if you want to use legacy (for HTML) encodings.

Comment: No I didn't, I have found more advanced text editor with a possibility to change encoding and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I actually cannot cuz Im integrating to a system that require iso-8859-2 encoding

Comment: You _should_ be able to use UTF-8 on your page, and only for submission to the external page use an alternative encoding through `accept-charset="ISO-8859-2"` on the form. That _should_ work on all modern browsers, but historically didn't in _all_ browsers…

Comment: @deceze I did something like that in the first code snippet, but I get some unreadable chars on the receiver page, can you take a look on that form?

Comment: Solved, I just have to remove the meta tag Thank you all

Comment: @OskarOskar: but so not not use HTML5 DOCTYPE. Do not mix standards

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the actual text is not actually ISO-8859-2 encoded. You *denote* that it is, causing the browser to treat the bytes as ISO-8859-2, but actually the bytes are UTF-8 encoded. The UTF-8 encoded bytes for "Ńóô" are `c583 c3b3 c3b4`. The ISO-8859-2 interpretation of this byte sequence is something like "ĹĂłĂ´".

Actually save the HTML file as ISO-8859-2 in your text editor.

Comment: OR change the ` ISO-8859-2` to UTF8

Comment: Yes It works, thanks! I have found more advanced text editor that gives me a possibility to change encoding.